# /tmp has changed to read only

Tags: linux, filesystems

Our sysadmin has left for the day and our production box (which isn't heavily used) is giving messages like

```
Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_1d2d_0.MYI' (Errcode: 30)
```

`/tmp` has gone read only by the looks of it.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Trying `umount /tmp` gives me `device is busy`.

Would like to not restart.

`/etc/fstab`:

```
LABEL=/                 /                       ext3    defaults,usrquota        1 1  
LABEL=/var              /var                    ext3    defaults,usrquota        1 2  
LABEL=/boot             /boot                   ext3    defaults        1 2  
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0  
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0  
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0  
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0  
LABEL=SWAP-sda3         swap                    swap    defaults        0 0  
/usr/tmpDSK             /tmp                    ext3    defaults,noauto        0 0
```

`mount` command output:

```
 /dev/sda5 on / type ext3 (rw,usrquota)  
 proc on /proc type proc (rw)  
 sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)  
 devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)  
 /dev/sda2 on /var type ext3 (rw,usrquota)  
 /dev/sda1 on /boot type ext3 (rw)  
 tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)  
 none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)  
 /usr/tmpDSK on /tmp type ext3 (rw,noexec,nosuid,loop=/dev/loop0)  
 /tmp on /var/tmp type none (rw,noexec,nosuid,bind)  
 sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
```

`df -h` command output:

```
 Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
 /dev/sda5             200G   35G  156G  19% /   
 /dev/sda2              24G  7.2G   16G  32% /var  
 /dev/sda1              99M   17M   78M  18% /boot  
 tmpfs                1013M     0 1013M   0% /dev/shm  
 /usr/tmpDSK           485M   21M  439M   5% /tmp
```

I fixed it by the following

`lsof | grep /tmp` showed me what was using `/tmp`. I stopped the service (xfs) then managed to run an `fsck`, fix the inconsistencies and it's now back up :)

But now it's gone down again. Suggestions?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -ld /tmp`?

Comment: @quanta - drwxrwxrwt 6 root root 1380352 Oct 25 15:32 /tmp/

Comment: Add contents of /etc/fstab and output of mount and df -h

Comment: And this is why we have on-call rotas. My suggestion? Ring your sysadmin and hope they are feeling generous.

Answer (score 1):

No idea what your sysadmin is trying to achieve with a loop mounted file `/usr/tmpDSK` for `/tmp` (and then using a journaling filesystem for it).
There's plenty of space on your root partition `/dev/sda5`, so I guess if you just `umount /tmp` you'll be fine until he's back.